# Should I load fragments in a container or load new activities after BottomBar/tab click?

Tags: android, android-fragments, xamarin, tabs

I am building a Xamarin Android app and need to make a design choice. I am still rather new in Android development, and don't know any other developers in my area personally that I can ask for help on this matter.

The app has a "BottomBar" with several buttons / tabs. If a button is clicked, a new screen should appear.

[image]

All 4 screens contain a lot of data, mostly lists (or RecycleViews?) of images with text and when clicking on a listItem or similar, an associated detail screen should appear.

At this point I wrote code that loads new activities when I click on one of the bottombar buttons. E.G., btnA loads activityA, btnB loads activityB and so on. The BottomBar is regenerated in each new activity and also keeps track of its instance State, so if I am in activityA and click on btnB, ActivityB loads and in activityB btnB is highlighted as the active tab, without me having to write a single line of code. Basically, *this is working great out of the box*.

I am wondering however if I should add a big fragment container in a host activity, and load different fragments in that container on BottomBar button clicks instead. Maybe this approach has a performance benefit or some other benefits that I am not aware of as yet. As for now, we don't have any intentions to create a tablet version, we only want to create a mobile version of the app. I understand that I can reuse fragments with a bigger screen estate (tablets), but this should not be necessary.

Again, everything is working ok as it is, but I am only at the beginning of building the app, and would like to make good design choices early.

The BottomBar component that I am using (Xamarin c#):
https://github.com/pocheshire/BottomNavigationBar

The above version is a port of this (Java):
https://github.com/roughike/BottomBar

Any advice is appreciated...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for long waiting.

If you want to follow the path that Google recommends in their guides that you need swap the fragments in the container by pressing the tab.

[Link to Google guides](https://material.google.com/components/bottom-navigation.html#bottom-navigation-behavior)

Comment: Thank you! I already chose the path of using fragments, but did not know about this google guide, very helpful indeed. And thank you for coding your nice component, I appreciate it very much :)